# Include once capability in Inno Setup Preprocessor?

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating a library of script methods and only want to include them when needed in my installers.

Some of the methods need to use other methods so I was putting the `#include "filename.iss"` for the needed methods in the file with the method that needs it.

However, if I include two files in an installer script file that also include a common file I get a "`Duplicate identifier`" error in the second file that includes it.

I've searched for something like `#include-once` but can't find any results for it.

To reproduce you can just include the same file twice:

```
#include "AddReplaceLinesInFile.iss"
#include "AddReplaceLinesInFile.iss"
```

The only way I can see to avoid this is to not put the includes in the files with the methods that need them and just add them in the main installer script.

I'm leaving the includes in the top of the method files that need them but commenting them out - for documentation purposes and to make it easy to copy and paste them into my main installer script. However I'd prefer to use something like an `include-once` capability.

Does Inno Setup have anything like `include-once` or a way to test for an already defined method so I could create something similar?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same trick as is used in C/C++, the [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, an **#include guard**, sometimes called a **macro guard**, is a particular construct used to avoid the problem of *double inclusion* when dealing with the include directive.

---

Surround the code in the included file with `#ifndef UniqueName`, `#define UniqueName` ... `#endif`:

```pascal
#ifndef IncludeIss
#define IncludeIss

procedure Test;
begin
end;

#endif
```

The `UniqueName` is typically the same as filename, with punctuation removed (to make it a valid identifier). I.e. for `include.iss` the name can be `IncludeIss`.

---

See [Inno Setup Preprocessor: #ifdef, #ifndef, #ifexist, #ifnexist](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as include-once.

Inno Setup is Pascal based where *functions (and procedures)* are **global**! There are no private ones.

*Preprocessor Symbols* are scoped to the .iss file and to make them global use **public** keyword.

*Variables* have really unpleasant behavior: if you define global variable (in [Code] section) with the same name as local variable you never know into which variable the value is really assigned.

Compiler does not check this which is really bad.